# Need advice - design repository for ASP.NET Core MVC / C# project

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, repository

I hardly had used design patterns, interfaces and .NET Core before so I need some advice to get a good design for my current project.

I have created a standard ASP.NET Core MVC website and need it to access data from different databases. I intend to put the database access in a separate class library project as repository to achieve loose coupling and be able to change any data implementations in the future if necessary.

For this I just use normal SQL with SQL Server, not Entity Framework Core, to have more understanding and grip on the SQL what I am doing.

The website has a left sidebar with different menu options to access different databases for multiple authorized users. For now 1 function is to create a XML file from data in the database and a 2nd function would be to update existing data in a table in another database. In future the MVC will be like a console for the user to perform more automated work.

My questions:

1. Should I make one class library per repository per a specific database or just 1 giant class library where different interfaces and implementation exists for every specific database?
2. I reference the class library in the ASP.NET Core MVC project. Can I create instances with dependency injection for every specific repository in the `Program.cs` in the ASP.NET Core MVC project? Will it see classes in the class library?
3. Also is it advisable to set the builder service to `AddScoped` in the dependency container? Or `AddSingleton`?
4. I wonder also if it is not better to implement the repositories as Web API... just passing Json back and forth

I am using Visual Studio 2022, .NET Core 6.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestion

Comment: 1. It depends, but definitely don't put different databases code in a single library. Read about layered or onion architecture. 2. I don't understand the question, don't create stuff manually in `Program.cs`, use DI. 3. Read [service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes). 4. It depends. Will somebody else use that API? Maybe not now, but in future? If it just for you, I'd advise keeping the data flow inside.